# Playing a video with JavaCV and FFmpeg

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-videoview, javacv

So, I'm developing a custom video player for Android but I need to play more than the android supported video files `(mp4, 3gp...), like wmv, avi, flv.`

At this time I do already convert any video type to .mp4 and I'm able to play them after recoding, but I have no idea how can I play those `wmv`, `avi` files without recoding them to `mp4` video formats.

Is there any way I can play any video on Android without recoding them?
`JavaCV` + `FFmpeg` library already working, just don't know how to do that.

By the way, heres the code that I'm using to recode videos:

```
public static void convert(File file) {

    FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber =
            new FFmpegFrameGrabber(file.getAbsolutePath());

    IplImage captured_frame = null;

    FrameRecorder recorder = null;
    recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("/mnt/sdcard/external_sd/videosteste/primeiroteste.mp4", 300, 300);
    recorder.setVideoCodec(13);
    recorder.setFrameRate(30);
    recorder.setFormat("mp4");
    try {
        recorder.start();
        frameGrabber.start();
        while (true) {
            try {
                captured_frame = frameGrabber.grab();

                if (captured_frame == null) {
                    System.out.println("!!! Failed cvQueryFrame");
                    break;
                }
                recorder.record(captured_frame);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been searching for quite some time and still no answers. Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

first you create the CanvasFrame then use "canvas.showImage(captured_frame);" instead of  "recorder.record(captured_frame);"

Here is the code:

```
public class GrabberShow implements Runnable 
{
    final static int INTERVAL=40;///you may use interval
    IplImage image;
    static CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("JavaCV player");


    public GrabberShow() 
   {
        canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }


    public static void convert(File file) 
    {

    FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(file.getAbsolutePath());

    IplImage captured_frame = null;

    FrameRecorder recorder = null;
    //recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("/mnt/sdcard/external_sd/videosteste/primeiroteste.mp4", 300, 300);
    recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("D://temp.mp4", 300, 300);
    recorder.setVideoCodec(13);
    recorder.setFrameRate(30);
    recorder.setFormat("mp4");
    try {
        recorder.start();
        frameGrabber.start();
        while (true) {
            try {
                captured_frame = frameGrabber.grab();

                if (captured_frame == null) {
                    System.out.println("!!! Failed cvQueryFrame");
                    break;
                }
                //recorder.record(captured_frame);
                canvas.showImage(captured_frame);
                Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public void run() 
{
    convert(new File("D://aes.mp4")); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GrabberShow gs = new GrabberShow();
    Thread th = new Thread(gs);
    th.start();
}
}
```

Comment: He asked about android, I think you answered abput desktop app

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can play any video on Android without recoding them?

Why are you recording the Video?? There is no need to record the video. JavaCv.

This is sample code for giving you the idea, how you can achieve it.

```
FrameGrabber grabber = new FrameGrabber(videoFile);
grabber.start();
BufferedImage image= null;
while((image=grabber.grab())!=null){
   // TODO set the image on the canvas or panel where ever you want. 
}
grabber.stop();
```