# Android: Playing .avi video file using default player

Tags: android, video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android intent for playing video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572107/android-intent-for-playing-video)

How to play .avi video file using default player.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER);
File file = new File(arrGetVideoList.get(position));
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), " video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

arrGetVideoList is a arraylist contains videofile path.

Can anyone help me.

Comment: arrGetVideoList.get(position) return example? is string?

Comment: Remeber Your Device should support .avi file extension videos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this works for me.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri data = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    .getPath()
    + "/Test.avi");
intent.setDataAndType(data, "video/avi");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't play .avi files using the default player on Android.

You may take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html to see what formats are supported on Android

If you really need to play other formats than the supporteds by Android, you should take a look at FFMpeg.

Here are some usefull links about JavaCV/ffmpeg on android:

http://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/javacv/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770376/playing-a-video-with-javacv-and-ffmpeg

Hope I could help :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply let me check

Comment: If any of the answers were useful, please vote it as accepted as correct answer :)