# How to Play a Video file in javacv / javacpp

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, javacv, javacpp

Does someone have some example code to play a simple video file with the current javaCPP/javaCV version and the FFmpegFrameGrabber?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770376/playing-a-video-with-javacv-and-ffmpeg) solution, but its apparently too old and does not work with the current javacv version because of an incompatible FrameGrabber interface (returns a "Frame"-Object instead of an "IplImage"-Object). If I change the code  manually (using Frame instead of IplImage), it returns the error message:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/bytedeco/javacv/FFmpegFrameGrabber.startUnsafe()V @1291: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Type 'org/bytedeco/javacpp/avutil$AVFrame' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'org/bytedeco/javacpp/Pointer'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @1291
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/bytedeco/javacv/FFmpegFrameGrabber', integer, 'org/bytedeco/javacpp/avformat$AVInputFormat', 'org/bytedeco/javacpp/avutil$AVDictionary', integer, 'org/bytedeco/javacpp/avcodec$AVCodec', integer, integer, integer, integer }
    stack: { uninitialized 1283, uninitialized 1283, 'org/bytedeco/javacpp/avutil$AVFrame' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2a01 b500 332a bb00 8659 01b7 0087 b500............
```

FYI: I'm comparing different java libraries for playing video files and extract their pixel data (xuggler, vlcj, ...) and search for the best one. I really like to include javacv in my tests but it's not working :(